# Is this a sign of a failing CPU?

Tags: boot, cpu

Seems like my Alienware 17R3 bit the dust. I think my CPU went bad. I am about to reinstall the bios because at this point I have already reset it and no improvements. I have tried top re-install/repair windows with two separate certified USB flash drives, now I have moved on to attempt to inspect my current installation of Windows on this machine with a bootable kali-linux drive but even my bootable version of kali wont run on this machine anymore. Bootup starts normal but while attempting to move the program into the machine it hangs up on what appears to be the CPU related process. I don't know what line it is but it reads as such...

[     0.0989260] .... node #0, CPUs:       #1 #2_

That last underscore is where the program stops and it just stays blinking. I can hit any button but nothing happens. This is a core-176700HQ.

Comment: Please give more details about how it behaves strange under Windows or other OS(another Linux distro or BSD), and why do you suspect BIOS? Does it even have problem when you are in BIOS? also you can try Memtest to check your memory first.

Comment: No matter what I do I can not even launch recovery tools while operating under Windows. If I am luck I will get a screen with an error code. Most times I just get a blue screen with a frowning face and an incomplete message. I did check memory, no problems there. Also, battery checks out in BIOS. I suspect BIOS because I have been having a hard time loading any kind of OS or boot programs, but I guess that is not a completely clear indicator. That is why now I am curious about what else it might be.

Answer (score 0):

Could be CPU.  Probably more likely to be other things, like bad RAM, motherboard, BIOS, etc.  (Maybe PSU.)  If you're getting even that far, it seems like the CPU is functioning (at least at a basic level).

Might be an issue with whatever normally gets detected right after the CPU feature detection?

Comment: Not sure. I am trying to reinstall bios now. I still need to restart to be sure if BIOS reinstalled/updated with the version I just loaded, but I did get what appears to be an error code after it completed first time. Error says 'Invalid Opcode at A1F3 7379 0203 6574 206D 6977 6C6C 7020 706F 7520 2070 2061 656D '